# Weekly \ Monthly Percent Change in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-analysis

I have a pspsql table which is having a bunch of data like :

```
 timestamp  itemcode    price
1606780800  ALKCD   104
1606780800  GTNS    22
1606953600  ALKCD   108
1607126400  ALKCD   119
1607126400  GTNS    35
1607299200  ALKCD   128
1607299200  GTNS    34
1607472000  ALKCD   101
        
1609804800  ALKCD   121
1609804800  GTNS    48
1609977600  ALKCD   118
1609977600  GTNS    47
1610150400  ALKCD   123
1610150400  GTNS    49
```

And its goes on with million rows.. I'm trying to analyse to daily\weekly\monthly price percent change.

As on this table i have an also dailychange, weeeklychange and montlychange colum which is will be use as the between date in price change. For example: aug 2020 has a only 15 price for ALKCD but in September 2020 ALKCD has a 19 price.  In dailychange percentage column i can be success with LAG function:

```
    WITH daily_change_lag AS (
 SELECT
  *,
  LAG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY itemcode ORDER BY time) AS previous_1day_change
  FROM history
)
SELECT
    *,
   COALESCE(round((close - previous_1day_change)/previous_1day_change *100),0) AS percent_change
FROM daily_change_lag;
```

That func gives me daily percent change but what about the weekly\monthly? I searched on google and on stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything that could help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Monthly" does not seem well defined.

Comment: This question from dba.se is similar and can give you ideas: [Date range rolling sum using window functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114403/57105)

Answer (score 1):

If you have one row per day -- as your code suggests -- then you can use `lag()` for weekly:

```
WITH h AS (
      SELECT h.*,
             LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY itemcode ORDER BY time) AS previous_1day_change,
             LAG(price, 7) OVER (PARTITION BY itemcode ORDER BY time) AS previous_7day_change
     FROM history h
    )
SELECT h.*,
       COALESCE(round((close - previous_1day_change)/previous_1day_change *100),0) AS percent_change_1,
       COALESCE(round((close - previous_1day_change)/previous_7day_change *100),0) AS percent_change_7
FROM h;
```

It is unclear what you mean by "month".  For instance, what is one month before March 31?  You can easily adjust the above logic for something like 30 days or 28 days, if that suffices for your definition.